# Add multiple lines of CSS with JavaScript of the same property

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add multiple lines of CSS for the same property (overruling for multiple browsers) but I only see the last appended.

I see why this happens, but I have no clue on how to fix it. Changing the `=` into a `+=` didn't work either. How should I change this so they are all appended correctly?

```
    ribbon.style.background = '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, ' + config.ribbonColorStart + ' 0%, ' + config.ribbonColorEnd + ' 100%)';
    ribbon.style.background = '-moz-linear-gradient(left, ' + config.ribbonColorStart + ' 0%, ' + config.ribbonColorEnd + ' 100%)';
    ribbon.style.background = '-o-linear-gradient(left, ' + config.ribbonColorStart + ' 0%,' + config.ribbonColorEnd + ' 100%)';
    ribbon.style.background = '-ms-linear-gradient(left, ' + config.ribbonColorStart + ' 0%,' + config.ribbonColorEnd + ' 100%)';
    ribbon.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + config.ribbonColorStart + ' 0%,' + config.ribbonColorEnd + ' 100%)';
```

Comment: You don't need to fix it. Every browser will accept the one that it can interpret.

Comment: What's about writing all the values into an extra vraiable and append that to ribbon.style.background normally any browser will use it's own equivalent?

Comment: Why not create a new class in your CSS with all those styles, then just add or remove the class to the element?

Comment: If you really want to have all values assigned, you can use `ribbon.style.cssText = 'all-your-gradients'`, but it won't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to browser-detect it. Something like:

```
try {
  ribbon.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(...)";
  if( !ribbon.style.backgroundImage || ribbon.style.backgroundImage == "none")
    ribbon.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(...)";
  if( !ribbon.style.backgroundImage || ribbon.style.backgroundImage == "none")
    ribbon.style.backgroundImage = "-moz-linear-gradient(...)";
  if( !ribbon.style.backgroundImage || ribbon.style.backgroundImage == "none")
    ribbon.style.backgroundImage = "-o-linear-gradient(...)";
  if( !ribbon.style.backgroundImage || ribbon.style.backgroundImage == "none")
    // gradient not supported, fall back here
}
catch(e) {
  // gradient not supported and browser does't like bad values. Fall back here
}
```

It should be noted that `-ms-linear-gradient` has never existed: IE9 didn't support gradients, IE10 fully supports them.

Of course, you could just put the styles in a class and add that class to your element ;)

Comment: **WHY?** This does not make any sense.

Comment: @Prinzhorn What part doesn't make sense? If the browser can't understand the value you give it, it will either empty it or set it to "none". Or fail with an error, better edit to catch that.

Comment: You are not gaining anything by doing these checks. It's working perfectly the way the OP coded it.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Erm... no it isn't. Let's say the browser only recognises `-webkit-linear-gradient`. So the first assignment in the OP works. But then you're overwriting it with a bad value, causing it to fail and revert to having no background. It works in CSS because CSS is designed that way. JavaScript isn't.

Comment: Nope. Setting it to an invalid value _does not_ magically turn it into `none`. http://jsbin.com/EFOkoFa/1/edit

Comment: didn't know about this, interesting. But I guess I should go with adding a class and a style dom element